Convert range of numbers to average in a pandas dataframe cell
I have a pandas dataframe read from large spreadsheets provided through a survey. In a column that expects float input, some of the cell entries are expressed as "n1-n2" (where n1 and n2 are numbers). I need to go through such columns and convert each such instance to (n1+n2)/2. Can someone suggest a lambda apply function for this to do this in the most pythonic way?

read notice: [mre]

You can split values by - to 2 new columns, convert to floats and call mean:
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':['10-15','14-89','50-200', 45, 4.8]})

df['avg'] = df['col'].astype(str).str.split('-', expand=True).astype(float).mean(axis=1)

print(df)
      col    avg
0   10-15   12.5
1   14-89   51.5
2  50-200  125.0
3      45   45.0
4     4.8    4.8

If want processing only values with one - to same column:
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':['10-15','14-89','50-200', 45, 4.8]})

m = df['col'].str.count('-').eq(1)
df.loc[m, 'col'] = df.loc[m, 'col'].str.split('-', expand=True).astype(float).mean(axis=1)

print(df)
     col
0   12.5
1   51.5
2  125.0
3     45
4    4.8

